# Inputting matrices of varying dimensions in R

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop

I have the following problem, lets say i have a function `ss()` that produces data that always has 4 columns but differing number of rows, I want to store this output into an array

```
ss(M[1])  #matrix with 4 cols and 10 rows
ss(M[2])  #matrix with 4 cols and 20 rows
ss(M[3]) #matrix with 4 cols and 40 rows
```

Then I want to put these together in an array:

```
J<-array(40,4,3)
for ( i in 1:3){
J[,,i]<-ss(M[i])
}
```

But what happens is that for the first matrix with 10 rows the values are repeated to fill up the array, I want to have 0s after the data existing in M is filled. I then tried:

```
J<-array(40,4,3)
for ( i in 1:3){
dims<-dim(ss(M[i]))
J[1:dims[1],1:dims[2],i]<-ss(M[i])
}
```

But I feel that this method is not that efficient, is there a better way? Is there some way to use apply:

```
B<-lapply(M, ss)
```

but this is also extremely slow,( M has 10000 elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to create your object `B` without a loop would be:

```
B <- as.array(lapply(1:3, ss))
```

If you really want to force all matrices to have 40 rows, filling the non-data elements with zeros, you could create a version of `ss()` which returns a matrix with that number of rows. As in:

```
ss <- function(x) {
  m <- matrix(x, nrow = x*10, ncol = 4)
  rbind(m, matrix(0, nrow = 40 - nrow(m), ncol = 4))
}
```